# JQuery / CAML Undefined Error

Tags: development, jquery, caml

I found some code on line, see below, and changed it to meet my needs but when I run it I get:

Due Date
undefined

This is the only value in the list, but it should look like:

Due Date
01/31/2019

Below is the code.  Also I'm not a coder, so if you answer please show me what to correct.

```
<table width="70%" align="left" id="myHTMLTable" border="1"> 
   <tbody>
      <tr align="left"> 
         <td>
            <b>DueDate</b></td> 
      </tr>
      <tr align="middle"> 
         <td align="left">undefined</td> 
      </tr> 
   </tbody>
</table> 
<script type="text/javascript">

getMyListData() ;

function getMyListData()
{                     
        var method = "GetListItems";                 
        var webURL =  $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;                     
        var list = "Project Statement";                      
        var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +"</ViewFields>";
        var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Due-Date' /></OrderBy></Query>"; 


        $().SPServices
        ({
                    operation: method,
                    async: false, 
                    webURL: webURL,
                    listName: list,
                    CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
                    CAMLQuery: query,                                                                                     
                    completefunc: function (xData, Status)
                     {
                         $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() 
                         {
                              var vDueDate = $(this).attr("ows_Due-Date");

                              $("#myHTMLTable").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
                               "<td align='left'>"+vDueDate+"</td>" + 
                           "</tr>");
                           });
                   }
       });
       };

      </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are using the `internal field name` correctly for the "`Due Date`" column.

I think it's not `Due-Date` so you got

> an undefined error

---

**To get the internal field name**

- Open list settings.
- Below COlumns, Click on the column name.
- Look at the URL, and check the **Field** Query String value.

  ```
  Ex:  &Field=Due_x0020_Date
  ```
- In this case, the field internal name is `Due_x0020_Date`

**Finally,** in your code, update each Due Date occurrences with this internal field

```
var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Due_x0020_Date' /></OrderBy></Query>";
```

> Also, I suggest using the [U2U tool](http://www.u2u.be/Tools/wincamlquerybuilder/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) to get the internal name and
>   build your CAML query in a correct manner

Comment: Got the date, but it looks like 2019-01-31 00:00:00.  How do I change the format to look like:  31 January 2019?  I've tried a few different formatting options that I found on line, but when I run them the date then does not show at all.

Comment: Please close this question first by marking the answer as accepted, then ask this new question in independent question! Thanks!